# CSS question - repeating for x for two different images in different directions

Tags: css

I was playing around with an image on a site just for practice, and I was wondering if anyone could help me with a question.

I am trying to get the branch the snake is on extend both directions. (using background-repeat for x) However it will only match up with one side or the other. Is there a way to get x to repeat only for one side of the image, so I can use two slivers of the tree image and it will match on both sides?

Thanks for any input or insight you might have!

Comment: SNAKES ON A WEBSITE!?  Call Sam Jackson!

Answer (score 3):

How would that work? Imagine an image as being a sequence of characters `xyz`.

To repeat the image I need to use:

```
xyz,xyz,xyz,xyz
```

Unless the sides of the image (the `x` and the `z`) match, there's no way to repeat it without getting mismatches at the boundaries between repeats.

In other words, fix your image so that the sides match up.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I didn't think that was really going to work. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't specify this.

What you should do is split your page in 3 zones: `snake`, `left`, `right`. Then use different repeating backgrounds for left and right.

You could also fix the snake image so it matches up.

Comment: Oh, nice! Thanks so much for your help! Forgive the beginner question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-position xpos ypos` to set the starting point of the background. Move it up to coincide with the picture of the snake.